# Mobile menu toggle bug after changing Bootstrap's mobile nav break point

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

**http://leongaban.com/_work/portal/app/#/**

I changed the mobile break for my [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) app to 900 pixels instead of 768. I found the styles here: https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w

The CSS works great, the navbar will change to the mobile version when you shrink the window down to 900 pixels, instead of waiting till 768. However there is a strange bug now. If you click on the toogle button.

This HTML below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ng-scope" ng-controller="NavController as nav">
```

Changes to this for a split sec:

```
class="navbar-collapse ng-scope collapsing"
```

Then ends up as:

```
class="navbar-collapse ng-scope collapse in"
```

So the mobile menu gets shown for a split sec in the `collapsing` state, then goes away :(

What needs to happen is that `collapse` needs to change to `collapsed`. If I change the class to `collapsed` in Chrome inspector then the mobile menu will be shown and not hidden.

Any idea why changing the Bootstrap mobile break seems to be breaking in my project?
I thought it had something to do with my Angular controller, but I removed that code and the mobile menu toggle is still broken.

This technique works fine in this example here: http://www.bootply.com/105915

Comment: I'm really tempted to just not use the Bootstrap js and just write my own code to open and close the toggle. But still am very curious why this is breaking...

Comment: Yeah, you'd be better off using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootply you're referencing was for 3.0.3. The best way is to use LESS or SASS to adjust your breakpoints, including the menu collapse. The second best way is to use the customizer at GetBootstrap.com.

This is the least stable version since Bootstrap is always improving their CSS and changing stuff:

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/noyale/2/edit - BOOTSTRAP 3.2**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    } 
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
       display: none!important;
       height: 0px;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
   .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
      overflow-y: auto!important;
      display:block!important;
      overflow-x: visible!important;
      overflow-y:hidden!important;
   }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```